# Deleting a part of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to delete certain values in a cell and leave the rest in the cell.

For example I have these values in one cell:

Trash

Recycle

Delete

Erase

Store

Keep

Save

I want the values from Trash to Erase gone while the three other values stay. so we have:

Store

Keep

Save

Is this even possible to achieve?

Comment: You can use `=Find` Function and `=Replace` to achieve this

Comment: Is this an Excel question or a VBA question?  In Excel it is very easy using the built in Replace tool.  If you are asking how to do this in VBA you would need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried the replace functionality and handled the values as strings but didnt work that way.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `=Mid` and `=Find`

Formula: `=MID(A1,FIND("Erase",A1)+6,LEN(A1)-FIND("Erase",A1)+6+1)`

[image]